# How to check input property using rxjs in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a input property inside component:

```
@Input() mailbarcode: string;
```

Then I call service:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.trackMailingObs = this.documentCardRepository.getMailing(this.mailbarcode);
    }
```

Problem is `mailbarcode` sometimes `undefined` or `null`, therefore `getMailing()` fails.  How to fix it?

Yes, I can do this:

```
if (this.mailbarcode) this.trackMailingObs = this.documentCardRepository.getMailing(this.mailbarcode);
```

Comment: So, if you have already found the answer on your own, what is the actual question?

Comment: How to do that usin rxjs, I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right approach would be to use *OnChanges*. From the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges):

> Called before ngOnInit() and whenever one or more data-bound input
> properties change.

---

In order to check if the input value is present before proceeding ahead, make the following change:

```
@Input() mailbarcode: string;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if (changes.mailbarcode.currentValue) {
     this.trackMailingObs = this.documentCardRepository.getMailing(this.mailbarcode);   
   }
}
```

Comment: Why no in ngInit?

Comment: How to handle changes.mailbarcode? Just check `if (changes.mailbarcode)` call service?

Comment: Is it correct? `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes.mailbarcode) this.trackMailingObs = this.documentCardRepository.getMailing(this.mailbarcode);
    }`?

Answer (score 0):

if you I sure that Input proerty must pressents in component you can add `*ngIf` on parent and than rerender only if presents